# WebDriverManager in Selenium C# is not working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting below exception when I use webdriver manager in c#. Can someone please have a look and advise?

Code used:

***new WebDrivereManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());***

Result :

The remote server returned an error :(503) Server unavailable

Reference :

https://www.qafox.com/selenium-c-sharp-webdrivermanager-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

Selenium must be running in the machine, otherwise the error 503 appears.

Check Selenium server and retry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Alberto Martin Could you please elaborate? Are you asking to run selenium standalone via cmd? Or anything from visual studio itself?  But I don't see any such step neither in the above reference mentioned nor in the another YouTube video which I am referring https://youtu.be/DDWlhz0iCnA

Comment: I looked into the official documentation as well but no luck.https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net

Answer (score 0):

before install WebDriverManager packge
This is the correct code:
C#

new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).